# Drupal Multiple domains hosting with common core files

Tags: php, linux, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have multiple domains as site1.com , site2.com , site3.com etc. All are having different database and logos,files,media will be different. So i am using symlinks feature to host my websites.

Firstly i copied all drupal files into site1.com , Now i copied sites,themes folder to site2.com and added core,profiles,vendor,modules folders as symlinks.

Site2.com is accessing but it is just showing site1.com data. When i changed settings.php file for database as well it is not working.

I want to know how can i do this? I choosen this solution why because my hosting provider having file count restriction and i have 35 domains to host in drupal.

Comment: You need to configure Drupal for multi site, symlinks won't achieve this alone read more here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base

Comment: Refer the answer in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223525/drupal-8-multi-sites-in-subdirectories-not-working/223561#223561